# Get user input (items) and reprint them on the screen in a sorted order

Tags: javascript, html

So, i am very new, i am taking a course in web design.

My assignment is to build a form that takes user input 10 fields and sort the input then display it back in the web page with the current date and time.

I'll sort the time/date later for now..

First i created a form with all the said input fields using a table.
input type="text" required="required" name="Propellers" maxlength="20"  value=""
and so on...

Then i wrote a function using variables and then put the variables in an array named accessories:

```
<script>

function gopro() {
parts.sort();
parts.reverse();
var input = document.getElementById("Propellers").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Batteries").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Gimbal").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Micro_HDMI").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Camera_Housing").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Carry_Bag").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Stabilization").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Karma_Drone").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Karma_Grip").value;
var input = document.getElementById("Hero_6_Camera").value;
var accessories = [Propellers, Batteries, Gimbal, Micro_HDMI, Camera_Housing, Carry_Bag, Karma_Drone, Karma_Grip, Hero_6_Camera];
document.getElementById("parts").innerHTML = accessories;   

}
</script>
```

Then I call the function when button is clicked onclick="gopro()

to display (return) the input values on the page:

id="parts"

But when i click the submit button the form just resets. Wondering why the form just resets instead of producing output on the web page?

thx

Comment: share your `html` code also

Answer (score 0):

form gets submitted to its action attribute, if no action is provided, form is submitted to current page url

use `e.preventDefault()` in your function at start and then make calculations

Also in your code, you have assigned the `input` variable all the values one by one so how the `accessories` variable will have values you want???

Comment: Ok so i removed the default value of "_" for the input boxes. I am caling the function using a button in a table cell <td><button onclick="gopro()">Submit values</button></td>. Example i have seen have used this to call the function. Is this not valid?

Comment: @DRK, could you please share your HTML code as well?